# How to replace label content with .each

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, each, label

I want to write a script that would resize labels length if its longer than 30 characters, but can't find the reason why it stays the same.
jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/rokas_m/9g3bcamz/10/

HTML:

```
<label>labelislabelislabelislabelislabelislabelislabelis</label><Br/>
<label>kitaskitaskitaskitaskitaskitaskitaskitaskitaskitaskitas</label><br/>
<label>asdfasdfsadfasdfsdfdsftaskitaskitaskitas</label><br/>

<label>siaip</label><br />
<label>siaip</label><br />
<label>siaip</label><br />
```

jQuery:

```
$('label').each( function(){ 
    var string = $(this).text();
    var ilgis = $(this).text().length;
   if (ilgis > 30){
   var string = string.substr(0,17)+'...';
     $( 'label' ).innerHTML = string;
        console.log(string);
   }

}
);
```

Comment: replace `$( 'label' ).innerHTML = string;` with `$(this).innerHTML = string;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this `$( 'label' ).innerHTML = string;` with `$(this).html(string);`.

Here's the modified code:

```
$('label').each( function(){ 
    var string = $(this).text();
    var ilgis = $(this).text().length;
    if (ilgis > 30){
      var string = string.substr(0,17)+'...';
      $(this).html(string);
    }
   }
);
```

Comment: thanks! it worked, but can you explain why .innerHTML didnt?

Comment: `$( 'label' )` returns a jQuery object, and hence `innerHTML` property is undefined. Instead, `this.innerHTML` will give you the intended result.

Answer (score 3):

You can use .text() set the value by passing a callback function as its argument which will be called for each label, like

```js
$('label').text(function(i, text) {
  return text.length > 30 ? text.substr(0, 17) + '...' : text;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>labelislabelislabelislabelislabelislabelislabelis</label><Br/>
<label>kitaskitaskitaskitaskitaskitaskitaskitaskitaskitaskitas</label><br/>
<label>asdfasdfsadfasdfsdfdsftaskitaskitaskitas</label><br/>

<label>siaip</label><br />
<label>siaip</label><br />
<label>siaip</label><br />
```

---

Or

```js
$('label').each(function() {
  var string = $(this).text();
  var ilgis = string.length; //reuse the variable
  if (ilgis > 30) {
    string = string.substr(0, 17) + '...';
    $(this).html(string);//$(...) returns a jQuery object so don't have `innerHTML` property, also you need to target the current `label` not all of them
    //or just
    //this.innerHTML = string
    console.log(string);
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>labelislabelislabelislabelislabelislabelislabelis</label><Br/>
<label>kitaskitaskitaskitaskitaskitaskitaskitaskitaskitaskitas</label><br/>
<label>asdfasdfsadfasdfsdfdsftaskitaskitaskitas</label><br/>

<label>siaip</label><br />
<label>siaip</label><br />
<label>siaip</label><br />
```

Answer (score 1):

Refer this

```
$('label').each( function(){ 
    var string = $(this).text();
    var ilgis = $(this).text().length;
   if (ilgis > 30){
   var string = string.substr(0,17)+'...';
     jQuery(this).html(string);
        console.log(string);
   }

}
);
```